# Issue calling back into Java from C++ called during a GLSurcfaceView callback

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a GLSurfaceView created in a JAR file within my Android app.  In the GLSurfaceView callback for onDrawFrame, I call a native C++ method via JNI.
At this point, I believe I am in the GLThread, and in that native method, I am trying to call back into a Java class in my App's namespace and NOT into the namespace 
which made the call.  So, I am trying to explicitly attach to the UI thread before doing so, but I am not successful.

I am receiving the following error

```
W/dalvikvm( 4243): JNI WARNING: can't call Lcom/main/myapp;.updateView on instance of Lorg/myorg/myRenderer;
W/dalvikvm( 4243):              in Lorg/myorg/ImageRenderer;.renderImageFrame:()V (CallVoidMethodV)
I/dalvikvm( 4243): "GLThread 336" prio=5 tid=16 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x418029f8 self=0x400988a8
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   | sysTid=4268 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1362099424
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=83 stm=71 core=1
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   at org.myorg.ImageRenderer.renderImageFrame(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   at org.myorg.ImageRenderer.onDrawFrame(ImageRenderer.java:93)
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
I/dalvikvm( 4243):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

My C++ code looks like :

```
JavaVM * jvm;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_myorg_ImageRenderer_renderImageFrame
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jObj) {

 jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0);

        jclass javaClass = env->FindClass("com/main/myapp");
             if(javaClass == NULL){
                 LOGD("ERROR - CANNOT FIND CLASS");
             }

        jfloatArray viewArray = env->NewFloatArray(16);
        env->SetFloatArrayRegion(viewArray, 0, 16, glmatrix.data);
        jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(javaClass, "updateView", "([F)V");
        if(method == NULL){
            LOGD("ERROR - CANNOT ACCESS METHOD");
        }

        env->CallVoidMethod(jObj, method, viewArray);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(viewArray);

jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved){
    jvm = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_2;
}
```

Comment: The warning is about a call to updateModel(), your code appears to be calling updateView(), so they don't quite line up.  The error message is saying that the method isn't defined in the object you're passing in (the "this" pointer).  You could try replacing the FindClass() with a GetObjectClass(jObj) and see if the GetMethodID call fails.

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted the wrong msg earlier.  Edited it.

Comment: And, I originally tried with GetObjectClass() and had the same problem, that is why I switched to FindClass().  Either way, it can get/find the class and method, just cannot invoke the method.

Comment: You may want to try out [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/#Creating_Callback_Functions) to help you with that!

Comment: You're running afoul of the test in checkVirtualMethod() in CheckJNI.c.  The test checks to see if the object you're invoking the method on is an instance of the method's declaring class.  The object is a myRenderer, but the updateView method was declared in myapp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to call back into a Java class in my App's namespace and
>   NOT into the namespace which made the call

Yeah, that's the problem. You have looked up a *methodID* in class `com.main.myapp` but then you are trying to invoke that *methodID* on the original *jobject* instance of `org.myorg.ImageRenderer` ! If you want to invoke a method from another "namespace", you have several options:

1. the method must be static so that finding a class is enough and you don't need an object
2. the another object must be passed in the native method as a parameter
3. the another object must be accessible as member/getter of the original object (which declared your native method) and then accessed via JNI method lookup and call

Comment: Could a 4th option be to link the 2 shared objects and pass it to the other which derived from Java I am ultimately trying to get to?

Comment: Ahhhh you've just solved a huge chain of like 6 issues (the most recent stage was with new native threads in the android ndk not being able to access current class instances) with your reminder about static methods! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is called from Java, therefore you should not call `AttachCurrentThread`.

Your function receives from Java a reference to the `org.myorg.myRenderer` object, of which renderImageFrame() is a native method (every native method receives Java environment `env` as the first parameter, and its object reference, often denoted as `thiz`, as second parameter.

If you want to call a Java method updateView() for the `app` object of class `com.main.myapp`, you should first obtain a reference to this object. The easiest way is to pass it as argument to your function, so now it will be declared as

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_myorg_ImageRenderer_renderImageFrame(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject app);
```

Alternatively, you may find the `app` object from `thiz`, if a reference to `app` is a field of the `org.myorg.myRenderer`, or is returend by some method of this class.

Finally, you are probably right, and calling an `updateView()` method, which requires the UI thread, from a GL thread, is not a good idea. You should probably issue a `post`, or send a message, or simply call `runOnUIThread()`.